# Why do I get Argument exception when I try to use "Include("PropertyName")" in query EF?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following code

```
var query = BAL.ApplicationInfo.db.Items.Include("Units").ToList();
```

but it gives me this error

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

My Item entity has a property called "Units" , actually there is relation between `Items` and `Units` entities. However I want to load child records with parent records, but I am getting the above error whenever I try to query with above code.

Can someone help me to get this done ?

My Context is a DBcontext not a ObjectContext

Comment: It seems to me that `BAL.ApplicationInfo.db.Items` is returning `null`.

Comment: I supspect that .ToList() should be called to Items to get loaded , But IF I write .ToList() after db.Items then I cann't find the "Include" , so how am I supposed to do this ?

Comment: I think what I'm saying is that the result, when the entire statement is executed, of `Items`, is `null`.

Comment: No no , Items are not null if the statement executed, IF I normally  excute the following code var items = db.Items.ToList()  then I can get all the list of items but IF  I excute this code  var = db.Items ;  then I get no item in return

Comment: Does `var query = BAL.ApplicationInfo.db.Items.ToList();` return someting?

Comment: Yes , It does ,It returns a list of items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Actually the problem was I didn't have a `using` directive to `System.Data.Entity` namespace at the top of my class.

Even thought I could use `"Include("PropertyName)"` name in my query, I couldn't use  `"Include(x=> x.Childs)"`. But after adding `"using System.Data.Entity"` on top of my class I can use `"Include"` in these both ways on a query and my error is solved.