# Is there a version of "Include" with compile time error checking in Linq?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

Is there a version of "Include"  with compile time error checking in Linq ?

I have this code

```
var myquery =  list.Include("Childrens").ToList() ;
```

Is there a version of this "Include" method with compile time error checking enabled , As I have lots of relations and sometimes I need to change their names ,So If there is a version with compile time error checking that will be really helpful.

Please someone let me know if there is a overload of "Include" method with compile time error checking

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework you are using?

Comment: My entity framework version is 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myquery = list.Include(x => x.Childrens).ToList() ;
```

You need to import this namespace too `"System.Data.Entity"`

Comment: Please add this directive to your class  "using System.Data.Entity Check this link too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743029/why-do-i-get-argument-exception-when-i-try-to-use-includepropertyname-in-q

Answer (score 0):

You can do `.Include(o => o.Childrens)` by using the namespace `System.Data.Entity`